# Redux DevTools shows unexpected repetition of ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST after API call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I'm facing an issue with my Redux setup where, after dispatching **ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST** in my `getProduct` action and successfully fetching data from an API, the same action (ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST) seems to be dispatched again, instead of **ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS** or **ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL**. I've checked my action, reducer, and store configuration, but can't seem to identify the root cause.

**Reducer Code**

```
import {
  ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
  ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
  ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
} from "../constants/productConstants";

export const productReducer = (state = { products: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST:
      return {
        loading: true,
        product: [],
      };
    case ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        product: action.payload.products,
        productsCount: action.payload.productsCount,
      };
    case ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL:
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**ACTION CODE**

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
    ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
    ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST,
    ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
    CLEAR_ERRORS,
} from "../constants/productConstants";

export const getProduct = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        console.log(1);
        dispatch({ type: ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST });
        const { data } = await axios.get("/VC1/products/");
        console.log(data);
        dispatch({
            type: ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
        });
        console.log("s");
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL,
            payload: error.response.data.message,
        });
    }
};

export const clearErrors = () => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS });
};
```

**STORE CONFIGURATION**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import { productReducer } from "./reducers/productReducer";

const reducer = combineReducers({
    products: productReducer,
});

let initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

**Constants**

```
export const ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST = "ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST";
export const ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS = "ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS";
export const ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL = "ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL";
export const CLEAR_ERRORS = "CLEAR_ERRORS";
```

**Component Code:**

```
import { getProduct } from "./actions/productAction.js";
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import { useEffect } from "react";


function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProduct())
  }, [dispatch])
  return (
    <div className=".App">
      <MetaData title="HHH" />
      <Main />
      <About />
      <StarProduct />
      <Growing />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now in redux devtool as you can see ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST is coming twice
[image]

Under log monitor of redux devtool on second ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST i am getting this
[image]

In the Redux DevTools, I'm observing an unexpected repetition of ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST after dispatching it in my getProduct action. Despite successfully fetching data from the API, the action does not progress to ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS as anticipated. The action history in Redux DevTools displays a peculiar repetition of ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST. I've shared relevant sections of my code and would appreciate any insights or suggestions to help me identify and resolve the root cause of this unexpected behavior.

Comment: `state = { products: [] }`  products should be an object rather than an array?